# How do I plot the graph of $|x|+|y|=1?$

Tags: graphing-functions

When I plot the graph of $|x|+|y|=1$ in Desmos Graphing Calculator it comes like this -[image]

How do I graph this plot? Can someone guide me?

Comment: Break the equation down into 4 cases, one for each quadrant.

Comment: You can also write it as $|y|=1-|x|$. For $y>0$ (above $x$ axis) it is $y=1-|x|$ and for $y<0$ it is $y=|x|-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|x|+|y|=1$, you have $|x|\leq 1$. Now separate in 4 cases :

- $x,y\geq 0$ : then $|x|+|y|=1$ can be written as
  $$y=1-x$$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.
- $x\geq 0,y\leq 0$ : then $|x|+|y|=1$ can be written as
  $$y=x-1$$ for $0\leq x\leq 1$.
- $x\leq 0,y\geq 0$ : then $|x|+|y|=1$ can be written as
  $$y=1+x$$ for $-1\leq x\leq 0$.
- $x,y\leq 0$ : then $|x|+|y|=1$ can be written as
  $$y=-1-x$$ for $-1\leq x\leq 0$.

Comment: Or just do the case $x,y\geq0$ and then note the symmetry of the equation. Basically, $(x,y)$ is a point of this graph if and only if $(-x,y)$ is, if and only if $(x,-y)$ is, if and only if $(-x,-y)$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Break the equation $|x|+|y|=1$ as follows.
Case 1:
When $x\geq 0$, $y\geq 0$, then $|x|=x$ and $|y|=y$. Above equation turns into $x+y=1$ to give line segment AB.(By intercept form)
Case 2:
When $x\leq 0$, $y\geq 0$, then $|x|=-x$ and $|y|=y$. Above equation turns into $-x+y=1$ to give line segment AD.
Case 3:
When $x\leq 0$, $y\leq 0$, then $|x|=-x$ and $|y|=-y$. Above equation turns into $-x-y=1$ to give line segment DC.
Case 4:
When $x\geq 0$, $y\leq 0$, then $|x|=x$ and $|y|=-y$. Above equation turns into $x-y=1$ to give line segment CB.
[See the figure below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUW37.png)